# Object spread operator as a function parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, ecmascript-6

I was testing `Object spread operator` and wrote these code, but actually could not figure out how the object `user` is transferred into an `Array`. So i want to understand the flow of code. Thanks

```
 const user = {
   name:"JohnDoe",
   age:25
  }

function test(...user){

  console.log('isArray ', Array.isArray(user));  // true
  console.log(user);                             // Array [ {…} ]

}
test(user);
```

Comment: It's polyfill would be like `arr= []; arr.push({Object.keys[0]:Object.values[0]})`

Comment: Pass a second parameter to `test(user)` and see what happens.

Comment: Here's a good post called "[spread is not an operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508)" which explains the confusion with this symbol. What you're referring to is actually a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).

Comment: You’re not using object spread here, but [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

Comment: @BenWest
Thank you that really helped :))

Comment: @CodingIntrigue Thank you that really helped :))